# SharePoint REST API: Not able to get list by getByTitle when list name contains spaces

Tags: java, list, rest, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to fetch SharePoint list using the SharePoint REST API from my Java application.

When the list's name does not contain a space, it works. If it contains a space it does NOT work. For example when I do the following:
**http:(site URL)/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ONEWORD')/items --> it works**

But when I try on another list like this:
**http:(site URL)/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TWO WORDS')/items --> it DOESN'T work**

I tried encoding the list name with the following in Java:
**String encoded= URLEncoder.encode("TWO WORDS", "UTF-8");**
But it didn't work.

I know there are many questions about this same issue, however everyone is suggesting to get list items by **List GUID** but I can't use this solution as I'm developing a dynamic tool for several lists with the same name. (Not the same GUID).

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `%20` to replace space. In your case it will be like following url

```
http:(site URL)/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TWO%20WORDS')/items
```